# Larmor precession for time-changing magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, precession

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_precession) gives the formula for Larmor precession for the magnetic moment in an external field ${\mathbf B}$. But nothing at all is mentioned about whether the field can have a time dependence. Since it's a differential equation for  ${\mathbf J}$, wouldn't that change things significantly? Or are the results still valid, except the precession just happens about a vector which no longer is constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At any moment in time, the cross product of magnetic moment and field results in a torque which will cause instantaneous precession of the magnetic moment. If the field direction is constant the precession is about a constant axis; if the field changes in magnitude, the rate of precession will change accordingly; and if the direction of the field changes, so will the axis of precession.

Comment: @DepeHb isn't that you who asked about a solution of the equation of $d \vec n /dt$ ? What is different, say, mathematically, from what you ask now? Didn't you see my solution? It doesn't answer your question?